# Understanding Azure Functions HttpTrigger scaling algorithm

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to understand how Http triggered function decides when it should be scaled.

I found that for queue triggers IScaleMonitor implementations are used. Here they are for:[RabbitMQ](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-rabbitmq-extension/blob/ef1caf83d38ea1fcfbc459d3f8e66afc96db7a1f/src/Trigger/RabbitMQListener.cs) [Blob trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs/Listeners/SharedBlobQueueListener.cs) [Event hub 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/blob/5eb8543e47b448eb3b485a571a2ceb1ab404650f/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/Listeners/EventHubsScaleMonitor.cs) [Event hub 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/33afacd4f477003e18ebc8bf6cdeaf1f28f938e9/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/src/Listeners/EventHubsScaleMonitor.cs) [Kafka](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension/blob/71d7399637b80082b5d443f4ade26ea5112c7354/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka/Listeners/KafkaTopicScaler.cs) [Service bus 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/blob/32f8df8a62c38cb5ae4333875d73d60f981045a3/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/Listeners/ServiceBusScaleMonitor.cs) [Service bus 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Listeners/ServiceBusScaleMonitor.cs) [Cosmos DB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/1ba3588ffb54f52f54f0898b18dea15f6bec6e3d/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Trigger/CosmosDBTriggerListener.cs) [Storage queue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/Listeners/QueueListener.cs)

But I couldn't find any code that works for HttpTriggers. Does anyone knows where to look for http scaling algorithms?

Comment: they don't scale from HTTP calls. Best to put them in a queue to trigger scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function that uses HTTP triggers is scaled based on the setting of `maxConcurrentRequests` in host.json:

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "maxConcurrentRequests": 100,
    }
  }
}
```

Ducumentation is here: [Azure Functions HTTP output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#hostjson-settings)

Azure Function that uses a Service Bus is scaled based on the setting of `maxConcurrentCalls` in host.json file.

Example host.json file with maximum concurrent calls set to 10:

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ducumentation is here: [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#host-json)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bun unfortunately I tested maxConcurrentRequests and couldn't find any scenario in which this parameter somehow influences the scaling.

My test load profile is 500 rps and 100ms request duration
I tried the following configurations:
(maxConcurrentRequests, dynamicThrottlesEnabled): (1, true), (1, false), (100000, true), (100000,false).

In every scenario my test app scaled up to 5 instances.

Comment: Moreover, I found out that parameters maxConcurrentRequests and maxOutstandingRequests are taken into account only if parameter dynamicThrottlesEnabled is true. And the only thing they influence is returning 429 when their conditions are not satisfied.

Proof:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/852eed9ceef6ef56b431428a8eb31f1bd9c97f3b/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/HttpRequestQueue.cs

Appreciate your help, but I'm still striving to find out how is Http triggers scale.